# There's no set $X$ such that $P(X)\subset X$.

Tags: set-theory, self-learning

I want to show the above assertion, I guess I am not sure what's the definition of a set, I thought it's the basic building block.

Anyway, if the above titled assertion weren't true then for every $Y \subset X$ we will also have $Y \in X$, which should contradict $X$ being a set, but why is that?

Comment: There is no definition of a set.

Comment: Can you please specify what definition of a _set_ are you using?

Comment: This question is exercise 1.2 from Jech's third edition of Set Theory.

Comment: Also, $Y\subset X$ doesn't imply $Y\in X$. What it does imply is that $Y\in P(X)$.

Comment: I think it would be better if you precisely write out the definition of a set you are using rather than mentioning the book because I don't have the book you mention currently.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I meant if the above assertion were not true then if $Y\in P(X)$ then $Y\in X$ where $X$ is a set.

Comment: If $P(X)$ stands for the power set of $X$, then element in $P(X)$ are not even points in $X$...

Comment: @3x89g2 yes $P(X)$ stands for the power set of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal P(X)\subset X$ then $\forall Y:(Y\subseteq X\to Y\in X)$.   That is, all subsets of $X$ would be elements of $X$.

Now consider that $X$ is an element of the powerset of $X$ (ie $X\subseteq X$).   So...

Comment: Note that this contradiction makes use of the axiom of foundation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity

Comment: @ChristianSykes that's what was missing for me, in Jech's book he doesn't say explcitly in chapter 1 what this axiom means.

Answer (score 6):

If you know that no set can be an element of itself, then you can show that $P(X)$ is not a subset of $X$ by simply observing that $X\in P(X)$ while $X\notin X.$

If you don't know that, then you can still prove that $P(X)$ is not a subset of $X$ by using Bertrand Russell's trick: define the set $R=\{x\in X:x\notin x\},$ the set of all elements of $X$ which are not elements of themselves. (If no set is an element of itself, then $R=X$.) Then $R\in P(X)$ but $R\notin X,$ since assuming $R\in X$ leads to the contradiction $R\in R\leftrightarrow R\notin R.$

Answer (score 0):

So forgive my english and my informal definition of a set

A set is a group of *elements*. So for example A = {1,2,3} is a set with three elements, which are 1, 2 and 3

Now, P(A) is called the set of parts of A. This set is the set of all possible subsets of A. In this case, P(A) = {Ø,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}}

So the important thing to note here is that the *elements* in P(A) are *subsets* themselves, and not the original elements in A. It is important to understand what the elements of a set are. I'd love to give a detailed explanation but I lack in that department

Assuming you get what I stated above, to prove what you want to prove is really easy. 
Suppose that P(A) is a subset of A. Then EVERY element in P(A) is also an element of A. This quickly leads to a contradiction, since while A had numbers as its elements, P(A) has subsets of those numbers as its elements.

A quick way of proving this as absurd is noting that $A \in P(A)$. So if P(A) was a subset of A then $A \in A$ which is absurd